# Anaconda lists some environments twice

Tags: anaconda, conda

```
(base) PS C:\Users\<username>\Desktop> conda info --envs
# conda environments:
#
base                  *  C:\Users\<username>\Anaconda3
proj_1                   C:\Users\<username>\Anaconda3\envs\proj_1
proj_2                   C:\Users\<username>\Anaconda3\envs\proj_2
                         C:\Users\<username>\anaconda3
proj_2                   C:\Users\<username>\anaconda3\envs\proj_2
```

This is on Windows 10. There's also an old environment present in the `C:\Users\<username>\anaconda3\envs` directory that I deleted using `conda remove -n proj_0 --all` in the past. `C:\Users\<username>\.conda\environments.txt` file contents:

```
C:\Users\<username>\anaconda3
C:\Users\<username>\anaconda3\envs\proj_1
C:\Users\<username>\Anaconda3
C:\Users\<username>\Anaconda3\envs\proj_2
```

What's up with all the casing and repeat environments? I don't remember changing anything manually. I've just tried removing the old environment dir (`proj_0`) manually, but got an error saying the folder is open in another program (I'm guessing conda).

Edit: `conda config --show envs_dirs` output:

```
envs_dirs:
  - C:\Users\<username>\Anaconda3\envs
  - C:\Users\<username>\.conda\envs
  - C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs
```

Comment: What does `conda config --show envs_dirs` output?

Comment: Put the output in the post under Edit (couldn't format correctly in a comment).